# How to resize table inside of another table?

Tags: html, css

I have a table that is nested inside of another table and I cannot resize by changing the width and height.

Comment: `table-layout: fixed` I think?

Comment: I have tried this using css width/height, and by using html "width" and "height" properties without issues. Remember if you're doing HTML, you should not, but also it's "600" instead of "600px"

Comment: @Mr_Green Do I put table-layout: fixed on parent table or nested?

Comment: Can you show what you tried?

Comment: @How can I show it?

Comment: @JoeySmith show the code that you have tried. Such as how did you create the table.

Comment: I am using quicktable https://github.com/joeybuczek/react-quicktable

Comment: @JoeySmith improve your question and add some code.

Comment: Its too much code to add. I do not know what to do.

Comment: In that case, I cannot help you.

Comment: I am not clear whether you are setting the widths of both tables or whether you are using waists and height attributes or CSS, or a combination. Please show the basic HTML and the relevant CSS. You can use your browser dev tools inspect facility to find the actual generated code.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

table.table_parent {
  width: 300px;
}

table.table_child {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}


table.table_child td {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<table class="table_parent">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table class="table_child">
        <tr>
          <td>
            lorem ipsum
          </td>
          <td>
            lorem ipsum
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            lorem ipsum
          </td>
          <td>
            lorem ipsum
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It is not working with my code

Comment: try to add !importand with your css, like width: 200px !important;

Comment: I tried that it does not work.